# can we set our ip address to be used in Perl SSLeay request?

Tags: perl, openssl, cgi, http-request, webproxy

I'm modifying [CGIProxy](http://www.jmarshall.com/tools/cgiproxy/nph-proxy.cgi.txt) to be enable to pass client IP address to remote/target, so remote will identify that the request is from client (not proxy server). Is it possible to do this thing? CGIProxy uses SSLeay for sending request to SSL server. But I need to pass client IP address through all protocol provided (http, https, ftp). I'm not really understand about both of proxy concept and network programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a proxy is not source-transparent, e.g. it will have it's own address as the client address in the connection to the target server and not the original client address. This is especially true for a CGI-script working as a proxy like in your case. This behavior is independent from using a TLS or a plain TCP connection.

But some (often misconfigured) servers check for an X-Forwarded-For request header to determine the original client IP. This header can be set from inside the proxy, but again this is independent from using TLS or plain TCP.

Comment: I'd like to conclude your answer, please cmiiw
1. X-Forwarded-For request header need to be set manually
2. target server need to be configured to be able read X-Forwarded-For. If target server is not configured to check X-Forwarded-For request header, proxy can't pass the original client IP
is it correct?